# Make a payment into someones paypal account using PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I have a website where I need to reward users for their involvement by paying money into their paypal account. I have a paypal business account, and would like to know if it is possible to put money into their account automatically from just having their paypal account email address.

I am developing my website using php. Ideally, I would like to have a script on my server that when executed transfers money from my business account into their paypal account.

I am new to paypal, and having looked around I am getting confused as to all of the different APIs that are in use! MassPay keeps coming up but if possible I would rather I didnt have to pay the 2% charge on each payment - is there any other options?

The payments are not for goods or services and so could be classed as a personal transfer, would this eliminate any fees?

So my questions are:

1) Is this possible?

2) Which API is most suitable?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! I know I'm a bit late but...were you able to do it? I need the same thing for my website and I'm finding it really difficult to perform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but you're going to end up paying a transaction fee. I would recommend you do a batch process (that is, do one large payment request scheduled at a certain time of day) through PayPal's Mass Payment API.

You can read more about this API and how to use it [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_masspay).

The way PayPal stays in business is by collecting these transaction fees. If it didn't collect them, it wouldn't be nearly as successful.

If you're looking at having more options on the transaction, including some ways to try and shift around who pays the fee, you may want to look at [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/content/introducing-adaptive-payments#id091QF0N0MPF).

Comment: But the payment is not for services or a purchase, and so if the payment were to be classed as a personal gift would I still have to pay the transaction fees? This will always be GBP to GBP in the UK..

Comment: To my knowledge the only thing that by default doesn't have transaction fees is the Send Money function for personal purposes. I don't, however, think there is an API for this. PayPal might have special programs for gifts. I'd recommend contacting their Support/Sales department for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to generate a paypal button in the following URL:
https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_donate-intro-outside

and place it at your page... You'll still have to pay some fee (although it's a low one)